# count total where column not empty

Tags: mysql

Here is the visual presentation what I'm trying to do-

[image]

7 days name as column. If any column contains any data, (not empty) then, it's count as 1.
Trying to get total count for each usernmae. i.e- adam will be 3, eve: 2, sam: 1

What I've tried-

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM roster WHERE `username`='$username' 
AND `sat` != '' AND `sun` != '' AND `mon` != '' AND `tue` != '' AND
`wed` != '' AND `thu` != '' AND `fri` != ''";
```

how to do it ?

Comment: Is the table at the top of your question your actual data or what you are *trying to do*?

Comment: @forpas: not actual data. what I'm tying to do with real data, counting how much duty each username has where sat, sun, mon .. each day name column has data like Morning, Evening, Night shift.

Comment: Then post sample data to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas: Updated

Comment: I asked in my previous comment if the top table in your question is your actual data and you replied no. So where is your sample data?

Comment: @forpas: My bad, yes the table is real data. I thought you asked if row values are real or not.

Comment: Revise your schema. Decorum prohibits further comment on the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the empty column values are `NULL`s then sum the 7 boolean expressions:

```
SELECT username,
       (sat IS NOT NULL) + (sun IS NOT NULL) + (mon IS NOT NULL) + (tue IS NOT NULL) + 
       (wed IS NOT NULL) + (thu IS NOT NULL) + (fri IS NOT NULL) AS total 
FROM roster 
WHERE `username`='$username'
```

If the empty column values may also be empty strings:

```
SELECT username,
       (COALESCE(sat, '') <> '') + (COALESCE(sun, '') <> '') + (COALESCE(mon, '') <> '') + (COALESCE(tue, '') <> '') + 
       (COALESCE(wed, '') <> '') + (COALESCE(thu, '') <> '') + (COALESCE(fri, '') <> '') AS total 
FROM roster 
WHERE `username`='$username'
```

Comment: Thanks and same.

Answer (score 1):

To display the groups of usernames instead of a single username remove `username='$username'` as that would limit the result to a single username.

Instead group the values by the username column

```sql
GROUP BY username
```

The `GROUP BY` clause is not needed if the intention is for a single username `WHERE username='$username'`.

`COUNT()` works by counting the number of rows within the result set.

`WHERE sat != '' AND sun != '' AND mon != '' AND tue != '' AND wed != '' AND thu != '' AND fri != ''` would limit the result set to rows that ALL of the column were not empty.

To retrieve the `total` value for each of the columns appropriately when the values are not empty, you would need to remove the `WHERE` clause  and replace `COUNT(*)` with a series of `SUM(column != '') + SUM(column2 != '')` conditions.

**Query** [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t7MuQzdSEUEW7yAQ6vcM2b/0)

```sql
SELECT
  username,
  SUM(sat != '') + SUM(sun != '') + SUM(mon != '') + SUM(tue != '') + SUM(wed != '') + SUM(thu != '') + SUM(fri != '') AS total
FROM roster 
GROUP BY username;
```

**Result**

```
| username | total |
| -------- | ----- |
| adam     | 3     |
| eve      | 2     |
| sam      | 1     |
```

---

If the `sat, sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri` columns contain `NULL` or `''` you would replace `SUM(col != '')` with `SUM(IFNULL(col, '') != '')` instead.

---

### Pivot Table

To display the results as a pivot table of `Evening`, `Morning`, and `Night` totals you would use a conditional on each value as separate columns and display the totals by using `GROUP BY username WITH ROLLUP`.

**Query** [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vZs8H5nguyWA2VRVCFuKya/1)

```sql
SELECT
  username,
  SUM(sat = 'Morning') + SUM(sun = 'Morning') + SUM(mon = 'Morning') + SUM(tue = 'Morning') + SUM(wed = 'Morning') + SUM(thu = 'Morning') + SUM(fri = 'Morning') AS `Morning`,
  SUM(sat = 'Evening') + SUM(sun = 'Evening') + SUM(mon = 'Evening') + SUM(tue = 'Evening') + SUM(wed = 'Evening') + SUM(thu = 'Evening') + SUM(fri = 'Evening') AS `Evening`,
  SUM(sat = 'Night') + SUM(sun = 'Night') + SUM(mon = 'Night') + SUM(tue = 'Night') + SUM(wed = 'Night') + SUM(thu = 'Night') + SUM(fri = 'Night') AS `Night`
FROM roster 
GROUP BY username WITH ROLLUP;
```

**Result**

```
| username | Morning | Evening | Night |
| -------- | ------- | ------- | ----- |
| adam     | 2       | 1       | 0     |
| eve      | 1       | 0       | 1     |
| sam      | 0       | 1       | 0     |
|          | 3       | 2       | 1     |
```

Comment: Let's not accept toxic behavior in this site +1.